# Copied checkbox elected value from one div to another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 `divs` with flip functionality. One div have multiple check boxed and another `div` is empty. When I selected check boxes in a div, these check boxes data values/ only labels has to be update in the another div when flip back. I have done flipping but the how to copy check box values/labels to another `div`?

My code: -

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/bootstrap.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <style>
        #two {
            height: 40px;
            width: 500px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 20px;
            left: 340px;
        }

       .vfront{
            background-color: lightgrey;
        }

        .vback {
            background-color:lightblue;
        }

        .vflipper {
            position: absolute;
            perspective: 600px;
            -webkit-perspective: 600px;
            -moz-perspective: 600px;
        }
        .vflipper .vfront, .vflipper .vback{
            -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
            -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;
            -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
            -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
            backface-visibility: hidden;
            -o-transition: transform .6s ease-in-out;
            -moz-transition: transform .6s ease-in-out;
            -webkit-transition: transform .6s ease-in-out;
            transition: transform .6s ease-in-out;
        }
        /* vertical flipping stuff */

        .vflipper {
            -webkit-transform-origin: 100% center;
            -moz-transform-origin: 100% center;
            -ms-transform-origin: 100% center;
            transform-origin: 100% center;
        }
        .vflipper .vfront {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            z-index: 200;
            width: inherit;
            height: inherit;
        }
        .vflipper.vflip .vfront {
            z-index: 900;
            -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
            -moz-transform: rotateX(180deg);
            transform: rotateX(180deg);
        }
        .vflipper .vback {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            z-index: 800;
            width: inherit;
            height: 150px;
            -webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
            -moz-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
            transform: rotateX(-180deg);
        }
        .vflipper.vflip .vback {
            z-index: 1000;
            -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
            -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg);
            transform: rotateX(0deg);
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="two" class="vflipper">
        <div class="vclick vfront">
            <div class="pull-left">Model</div>
            <label id="lbl"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="vback" id=val>
            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="name1">Option 1</label>
            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="name2">Option 2</label>
            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="name3">Option 3</label>
            <div class="pull-right"><input type="submit" class="vclick "></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.vclick').click(function(){
            $(this).closest('.vflipper').toggleClass('vflip');
        });
    });       
</script>
```

Here, the above code, flip is working perfectly . when I click on check boxes in the second div, the labels/ values has to be visible in the first div. Here, I am working with IE Edge browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the change event to listen for every changing in checkboxes.

The snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.vclick').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.vflipper').toggleClass('vflip');
  });
  
  
  //
  // Listen for change event 
  //
  $('.vback :checkbox').on('change', function(e) {
    //
    // get the labels list of all  checked elements
    //
    var result = $('.vback :checkbox:checked').map(function(index, element) {
      if (element.checked) {
        return element.parentNode.textContent + ' / ' + element.value;
      }
    }).get();
    
    //
    // add this text to the label
    //
    $('#lbl').text(result.join(', '))
  })
});
```

```css
#two {
  height: 40px;
  width: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 340px;
}

.vfront{
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.vback {
  background-color:lightblue;
}

.vflipper {
  position: absolute;
  perspective: 600px;
  -webkit-perspective: 600px;
  -moz-perspective: 600px;
}
.vflipper .vfront, .vflipper .vback{
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-transition: transform .6s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: transform .6s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: transform .6s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform .6s ease-in-out;
}
/* vertical flipping stuff */

.vflipper {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% center;
  -moz-transform-origin: 100% center;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% center;
  transform-origin: 100% center;
}
.vflipper .vfront {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 200;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
}
.vflipper.vflip .vfront {
  z-index: 900;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
.vflipper .vback {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 800;
  width: inherit;
  height: 150px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
  transform: rotateX(-180deg);
}
.vflipper.vflip .vback {
  z-index: 1000;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg);
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="two" class="vflipper">
    <div class="vclick vfront">
        <div class="pull-left">Model</div>
        <label id="lbl"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="vback" id=val>
        <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="name1">Option 1</label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="name2">Option 2</label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="name3">Option 3</label>
        <div class="pull-right"><input type="submit" class="vclick "></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy the check box label,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("button").click(function(){
            var sports = [];
            $.each($("input[name='sport']:checked"), function(){            
                 sports.push($(this).val());

            });
           $('#child').append(sports.join(", "));

        });
    });

</script>
    <form>
    <div id="main">
        <label><input type="checkbox" value="football" name="sport"> Football</label>

        <label><input type="checkbox" value="baseball" name="sport"> Baseball</label>

        <label><input type="checkbox" value="cricket" name="sport"> Cricket</label>

        <label><input type="checkbox" value="boxing" name="sport"> Boxing</label>

        <label><input type="checkbox" value="racing" name="sport"> Racing</label>

        <label><input type="checkbox" value="swimming" name="sport"> Swimming</label>

        <br>
    </div>
    <div id="child">

    </div>

        <button type="button">Get Values</button>

    </form>
```